# Error ORA-00902: invalid datatype using XMLSERIALIZE in oracle database

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I'm trying to indent an xml. Now I can generate it in one line, but I found out ORACLE XMLSERIALE. I did some test and it works fine, but This function change the encoding type in the first line in encoding windows-1252. So now I'm trying to set the encoding syntax into xmlserialize function, but the sql developer compiler gives me error ORA-00902: invalid datatype.

From Generation of XML Data from Relational Data - 8.2.7 XMLSERIALIZE SQL/XML Function
About ENCODING:
The ENCODING clause specifies the character encoding for XML data that is serialized as a BLOB instance. xml_encoding_spec is an XML encoding declaration (encoding="..."). If datatype is BLOB and you specify an ENCODING clause, then the output is encoded as specified, and xml_encoding_spec is added to the prolog to indicate the BLOB encoding. If you specify an ENCODING clause with a datatype other than BLOB, then an error is raised. For UTF-16 characters, xml_encoding_spec must be one of the following:

encoding=UTF-16BE – Big-endian UTF-16 encoding

encoding=UTF-16LE – Little-endian UTF-16 encoding

[Generation of XML Data from Relational Data](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adxdb/generation-of-XML-data-from-relational-data.html#GUID-55FE9CED-5B25-4DA2-9F9E-921DF8276EB8)

This is my code:

```
begin
    SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(Document XMLTYPE(doc_xml) AS CLOB ENCODING="UTF-8" INDENT SIZE = 4) into  doc_xml FROM dual;
    exception
      when others then
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQLERRM);
        return;
end;
```

doc_xml is a clob. I've tried without encoding and the function works fine, instead with encoding I get error ORA-902.

Can anyone give an idea to put correct syntax?

A minimal example to test my problem

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(Document XMLTYPE('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><p:FatturaElettronica xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:p="http://ivaservizi.agenziaentrate.gov.it/docs/xsd/fatture/v1.2" versione="FPR12"><FatturaElettronicaBody><DatiGenerali><DatiGeneraliDocumento><TipoDocumento>TD17</TipoDocumento><Divisa>EUR</Divisa><Data>2021-08-04</Data><Numero>200025</Numero><ImportoTotaleDocumento>1000.00</ImportoTotaleDocumento></DatiGeneraliDocumento></DatiGenerali><DatiBeniServizi><DettaglioLinee><NumeroLinea>1</NumeroLinea><Descrizione>REVERSE CHARGE</Descrizione><PrezzoUnitario>1000.000000</PrezzoUnitario><PrezzoTotale>1000.00</PrezzoTotale><AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA></DettaglioLinee><DatiRiepilogo><AliquotaIVA>22.00</AliquotaIVA><ImponibileImporto>1000.00</ImponibileImporto><Imposta>220.00</Imposta><EsigibilitaIVA>I</EsigibilitaIVA></DatiRiepilogo></DatiBeniServizi></FatturaElettronicaBody></p:FatturaElettronica>') AS CLOB INDENT SIZE = 4) 
FROM dual;
```

Comment: The documentation you quoted says "If you specify an ENCODING clause with a datatype other than BLOB, then an error is raised" - and you are using it with CLOB, so you get an error as expected. What is your database character set - xmlserialize should be picking that up; so just forcing it to say the wrong value might cause problems later.

Comment: I read that, but I can't understand without encoding type, the function changes the encoding type in the first line of my xml. XML file is correctly indented, but encoding='WINDOWS-1252', so I'm trying a way to solve it.

Comment: A [mcve] would be helpful. What data type is `doc_xml`, and what does it contain; you said it's changing the encoding, so whet do you see with just `XMLType(doc_xml)`? You might need to serialize as a BLOB, then convert that back to a CLOB with a specific character set; but it's unclear at the moment.

Comment: I put an example. Thanks. Here I pass a varchar2, but it's the same.

Comment: I was going to suggest you get it as a BLOB with an encoding you specify, and then convert that BLOB to a CLOB; but then [indent won't work](https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20Database%20Products/2313574_1.html). You could maybe change NLS_LANG to UTF8 before you connect, but that doesn't seem very satisfactory. The only other thing I can think of at the moment is to do a `replace()`, which isn't ideal either.